# Multiple action routing error in webapi MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have write the below configutation code in the webapiconfig.cs file for routing the multiple fintion. In the get methods I am getting the Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.String GetJobDetails(System.String) error.

Webapiconfig.cs code

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RendererAPi",
            routeTemplate: "shared/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RendererAPiStatus",
            routeTemplate: "shared/{controller}/{id}/status",
            defaults: new { action = "getJobStatus", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My controller code :

```
//post shared/rendererjob
    [HttpPost]
    public string createRendererJob(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return "teststring";
    }

    //put shared/rendererjob/renderGUID
    [HttpPut]
    public string DoPutRequest([FromUri(Name="id")]string renderGUID)
    {
        return renderGUID;
    }

    //get shared/rendererjob/renderGUID
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetJobDetails([FromUri(Name = "id")]string renderGUID)
    {
        return renderGUID;
    }


    //get shared/rendererjob/renderGUID/status
   [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage getJobStatus([FromUri(Name = "id")]string jobid)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        string uri = Url.Link("RendererAPiStatus", new { id = jobid });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

the 3 URL are working fine, the //get shared/rendererjob/renderGUID[HttpGet] is not working and getting the multiple action error in the browser.

Any one please suggest me on this.
Note : the Route method is not working in the MVC4 VS2012, and unable to instal any patches into my system for this.

Comment: tch tch! a space in url of your api call. Replace space with a hypen or something. Note: This is not the solution to your problem. Just sayin.

Comment: In which line the space is there, I am not seeing the space. Please post the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two GET methods with the same signature, so you need to differentiate them somehow. Try adding a Default Action Name to your methods that use the RendererAPi route:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Default")]
public string createRendererJob(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return "teststring";
}

//put shared/rendererjob/renderGUID
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Default")]
public string DoPutRequest(string id)
{
    return renderGUID;
}

//get shared/rendererjob/renderGUID
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Default")]
public string GetJobDetails(string id)
{
    return renderGUID;
}

//get shared/rendererjob/renderGUID/status
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getJobStatus(string id)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    string uri = Url.Link("RendererAPiStatus", new { id = id });
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Then change the RendererAPi route as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RendererAPi",
    routeTemplate: "shared/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {action = "Default", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

By the way you don't need to include the [FromUri] attribute for strings.

Comment: I did the changes, now the GET and Put methods of default action is not working. Getting the 404 error "Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"

Comment: My bad. If you remove the [FromUri(name)] attribute you will need to ensure the parameter names in your route and method match. I've edited my answer and changed the method parameter to 'id' from 'renderGUID'. I've tested this out and it works on my system here.

Comment: No problem. Another point: If you use Attribute Routing in WebApi2 you can avoid a lot of these problems.

Comment: Yes, it is worked without FormURI(name) attribute after change the parameter in webapiconfig.cs.
Thanks Jon :-)

Comment: Yes your right, the net45 haveing the Routing attribute right..But I am not allowing here to run any patch because it is shared VS.

Comment: Jon, could you please let me know how we can pass the arguments with controller. my path need to send is path --       
     http://localhost:12345/shared/rendererhealth?q={level}. Here shared is the common path, i have created the rendererhealth controler.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question but it would be better if you open a separate question and supply as much detail as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have already posted as aseperated question ur is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856259/need-to-pass-the-url-with-arguments-in-webapi. Please looking into that.