# Need to pass the URL with arguments in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the below URLs to pass the different API.

```
/shared/rendererjob -- I done
/shared/rendererjob/{jobId} -- I done
/shared/rendererjob/{jobId} -- done
/shared/rendererjob/{jobId}/status -- done

/shared/renderer/documentconverter/document -- I done
/shared/renderer/documentconverter/storage -- I done
/shared/renderer/documentconverter/callback -- I done

/shared/rendererhealth?q={level} -- **I dont know how to do this one**
```

How to write the webconfig.cs for this -- /shared/rendererhealth?q={level}

My config code is below.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RendererApi",
            routeTemplate: "shared/{controller}/{renderGUID}",
            defaults: new { action = "rendererJob", renderGUID =
                            RouteParameter.Optional     }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RendererAPiStatus",
            routeTemplate: "shared/{controller}/{jobid}/status",
            defaults: new { action = "getJobStatus", jobid = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DocumentConverterApi",
            routeTemplate: "shared/renderer/{controller}/{action}"

        );
```

The above code is working for what I have done.
Please let me know how to config the controler with arguments.

```
**How to achieve this path --       
 http://localhost:12345/shared/rendererhealth?q={level}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your routes appear to be very controller dependent, the first thing I would do is change your existing routing as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RendererApi",
    routeTemplate: "shared/rendererjob/{renderGUID}",
    defaults: new { action = "rendererJob", 
        renderGUID = RouteParameter.Optional,
        controller="rendererJob"     }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RendererAPiStatus",
    routeTemplate: "shared/rendererjob/{jobid}/status",
    defaults: new { action = "getJobStatus",
        controller="rendererjob" }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DocumentConverterApi",
    routeTemplate: "shared/renderer/documentconverter/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller="documentconverter" }
    );
```

Note you cannot have an optional parameter in the middle of a route so I have changed your RendererAPiStatus route so that jobid is mandatory.

Next add a new route at the end for your new resource:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RendererHealthApi",
    routeTemplate: "shared/rendererhealth",
    defaults: new { controller="rendererhealth" }
    );
```

You can then add your new controller method:

```
public class RendererHealthController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(int q)
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Note the above assumes you are using a GET request and {level} is an integer.

Comment: Hi Jon, Good Morning.Could you please help on the below issue.
 I need to converting the HttpRequestMessage to System.ServiceModel.Channels.Messages object. I have posted the issue on the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910745/converting-httprequestmessage-to-xml-objects.